# Hashmap not working correctly

Tags: java, hashmap, stringbuilder

I've built a string builder using a hash map but cannot figure out why when I try to print out words put into the builder, it's resorting to the else in countWords method. What did I do wrong that causes it print out `{=1}` and not the actual words a user inputs?

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HashStringBuilder {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String txt = readText();
    String[] words = txtToWords( normalize(txt) );

    HashMap<String, Integer> wordCount = countWords( words );

    for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++){
        System.out.println(wordCount);
    }
}

public static HashMap<String, Integer> countWords( String[] words ) {
    HashMap<String, Integer> wordCount = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    for( String word : words ) {
        if( wordCount.containsKey(word) ) {
            int count = wordCount.get(word);
            count = count + 1;
            wordCount.put(word, count );
        } else {
            wordCount.put(word, 1 );
        }
    }

    return wordCount;
}


public static String[] txtToWords( String txt ) {
    return txt.split(" ");
}

public static String normalize( String txt ) {
    txt = txt.toLowerCase();
    // You all can come up with a better way
    txt=txt.replaceAll("!", "");
    txt=txt.replaceAll(".", "");
    txt=txt.replaceAll("&", "");
    txt=txt.replaceAll("'", "");

    return txt;
}

public static String readText() {
    System.out.println( "Please enter the text to be processed.");
    String stop = "** STOP **";
    System.out.println( "Enter: \"" + stop + "\" to stop");

    StringBuilder results = new StringBuilder();
    Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );
    while( true ) {
        String line = input.nextLine();
        if( line.contains(stop)) {
            break;
        } else {
            results.append( line + " ");
        }

    }

    return results.toString().trim();
}


}
```

Comment: Try adding a print statement inside your `for(String word : words)` loop to print out `word` - seems like the strings being passed to `countWords()` aren't what you expect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to print `wordCount.get(words[i])`.

Also `replaceAll` takes a regular expression as 1st parameter. `.` means "any character" in regular expressions, so `txt.replaceAll(".", "")` actually removes any character. To remove just the dots, use `txt.replaceAll("\\.", "")`, i.e. add a slash to "escape" the special effect of R.E. dot. Or use `Pattern.quote`, like `txt.replaceAll(Pattern.quote("."), "")`

As @DavidConrad mentioned, the simple thing would be to just use `replace` instead of `replaceAll`, as this takes strings literally and you don't need the RE magic.

Comment: When I do that, no matter how many words I type, the output is 1 though

Comment: A better fix is to use [`String.replace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence)) instead of String.replaceAll. There's no need to use regular expressions, here, thus no need for Pattern.quote.

Comment: well if you have more than one dot, you'd have to repeat the replace, in which case replaceAll is neat, only you need to remember it takes REs

Comment: No, String.replace replaces all occurrences. "Replaces each substring of this string that matches the literal target sequence with the specified literal replacement sequence."

Comment: Thanks a lot @geert3 ! It turns out the problem was in the method with me trying to do all the txt stuff. Also adding System.out.println(wordCount.get(words[i]) + words[i]); Got exactly what I needed. I'm pretty inexperienced with hash code so thank you for the method call heads up.